# Can you embed an .ics file contents and link to it in html, ideally without using javascript?

Tags: html, ios, text, xhtml, embed

The text for an `.ics` file is rudimentary:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//appsheet.com//appsheet 1.0//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:Invitation from <<USEREMAIL()>> to talk about <<[MeetingTopic]>>
UID:c7614cff-3549-4a00-9152-d25cc1fe077d
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
DTSTART:<<[StartDateTime]>>
DTEND:<<[EndDateTime]>>
LOCATION:<<[MeetingAddress]>>
DESCRIPTION:<<[MeetingDescription]>>
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

I want to take the above, and embed that into my html. I have seen something similar done before:

```html
<audio id="offline-sound-press" src="data:audio/mpeg;base64,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"></audio>
```

However I can not find any resources explaining how to do this. My inquiries are misunderstood, suggesting to simply do:

```html
<a href="https://www.codexworld.com/newyork_event.ics">Apple Mail/Outlook Desktop</a>
```

This defeats the purpose, because I do not wish to be responsible for hosting an external file on my website, particularly one who's relevance expires.

Is it possible to simply embed the ics contents into xhtml, and have it so an apple device recognizes it?

If possible, I'd like to avoid heavy javascript libraries, as my website is designed to be low bandwidth.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like its little bit challenging coz **.ics** format is not natively supported by HTML. but give it a try using a data URL. it allows you to embed data directly into an HTML document using the **data:** scheme. also u can encode the **.ics** file contents as a Base64 string and include it directly in the HTML.

this could work but im not sure 100% coz this method has limitations. some email clients and applications may not recognize the data URL as a valid **.ics** file and may not handle it correctly. make sure that the **.ics** file content is properly URL encoded.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).